# Help to understand "reports Efe news" in this context

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, sentence-structure

> The Pentagon report, published on Friday, said China was developing long-range bombers and "likely" training its pilots for strikes against the US and its allies, **reports Efe news**.

I am not sure what **reports Efe news** is doing in this sentence, since it put "**The Pentagon report**" already at the beginning. Can someone help to explain it?

The [full source](https://www.business-standard.com/article/news-ians/china-lodges-protest-over-pentagon-report-on-planned-strikes-118081800171_1.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pentagon report is a noun, which is mentioned (reported, verb) by Efe News.

To read further about subject - verb inversion (e.g. "Joe said" vs "said Joe"), see here

[is-there-a-difference-between-joe-said-and-said-joe](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49862/is-there-a-difference-between-joe-said-and-said-joe)

Comment: Why not write as "Efe News reports" instead?

Comment: The verb may be placed before or after the noun. Either is acceptable. The world will end today, reports Efe News.  The world will end today, Efe News reports. Also verbs like says, alleges, suggests.